# "E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic:7: Extra junk at end of file" how to trouble shoot this?

Tags: apt, syntax

I typed `sudo apt update` in terminal, then I got the following error:

> E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic:7: Extra junk at end of file

The file contains:

```
1 #
2 # Xilinx Clocking Wizard Driver
3 #
4
5 config COMMON_CLK_XLNX_CLKWZRD
6     tristate "Xilinx Clocking Wizard"
7     depends on COMMON_CLK &&
```

Line 6 and 7 have two space gap before the wordings.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this entire conversation and all related comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51321/discussion-on-question-by-irshad-ahmed-e-syntax-error-etc-apt-apt-conf-d-10pe).

Answer (score 1):

Your `10periodic` file should look like this:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
```

In this file, the various lines has different meaning as given below:

1) `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists`

If this is set to "0" then it means that automatic update has been disabled.

If it is set to something **other than "0"** then it would imply the number of days for automatic update. e.g. setting it to "1" implies that your system will automatically update everyday.

2) `APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages`

If this is set to "0" then it means that automatic downloading of packages have been disabled.
But setting it to "1" = enable auto download package.

3) Similarly `APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval` can have "0" or **other number** specifying the number of days for *auto clean interval*.

You can also have another entry; `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade`. Setting it "0" will disable the automatic upgrade and "1" will enable the automatic upgrade.

I posted this answer because I thought your OS is Ubuntu. I'm not sure whether the `10periodic` file in *Elementary OS* looks like this or not. If not then my answer would be useless.

Comment: i reinstalled and yes, "10periodic" file in elementary os loki is same as ubuntu.

Comment: Happy to know. Have your problem been resolved?